# Difference between Visiting Lecturer and Lecturer?

Tags: career-path, job, lecturer

May you please tell me what is the difference between

> Visiting Lecturer

and

> Lecturer

Can Visiting Lecturer be considered an affiliation or academic staff, for Ph.D holders?

Comment: Which country? Lecturer has one meaning in the US and another in the UK, for instance

Comment: "Visiting" would suggest a temporary appointment.  At my US university, "visiting" appointments are considered as "temporary" and fall between "faculty" and "staff" and have their own  category on university books.

Comment: And what about Australia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surely depends on the circumstances.

Perhaps in some cases a "Visiting Lecturer" is someone not normally on the staff, who comes for one term or one year and serves as a Lecturer.  After that, going back to their usual job.

Whereas a "Lecturer" is a regular member of the staff.

Answer (score 1):

In Australia lecturers are paid. Honorary Adjunct Visiting and Emeritus aren’t.

In Australia a visiting lecturer is **generally** an unpaid position which allows access to the library. Visitors either have a substantive academic rank elsewhere or an equivalent.  Jane comes over to do a sabbatical here, Jane is appointed Visiting Senior Lecturer.

Other purposes unpaid

Honorary: retired with former rank or equivalent, they turn up for occasional seminars or coffee with their mates.

Adjunct: substantive external profession or trade, ie surgeon, coder, manager, fine artist

Emeritus: generally only professors (E) equivalent of full professors elsewhere. Like Honoraries but they’re so prolific you can’t stop them publishing full time, or they won a big gong (Nobel, field specifying monograph, etc)

These days you keep publishing or the title goes away. Often this is a way to rope in ERA publications.

Australian Ranks:

A Associate Lecturer / Tutor

B Lecturer / Tutor (course coordination)

C Senior Lecturer

D Associate Professor

E Professor